# What are the abreviations on tefillin cases?

Tags: tefilin, acronyms

I have seen two common abbreviations written on tefillin cases (I'm referring to the, most commonly red, cases that you put the tefillin into when you have completed wearing them):

תובב"א and פעיה"ק

What do these abbreviations mean?

[image: side 1][image: side 2][image: side 3]

Comment: Have you tried checking an acronym dictionary? Or just typing them into Google? The first Google result for each of those terms is a definition. This post doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: Does the box say anything on the other sides in order to understand the context of these terms? Perhaps a picture may be helpful, as numerous style containers are out there with different inscriptions.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikimilon](https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%91%22%D7%90) has the abbreviation

תובב"א

standing for

תיבּנה ותיכּונן במהרה בימינו אמן.

It should be built and established speedily in our days, amen.

The abbreviation is used for the 4 holy cities  ירושלים, טבריה, צפת וחברון; 
Jerusalem, Tiberias, Safed and Hebron.

And is used as in this example

בעיה"ק ירושלים תובב"א

where עיה"ק

stands for

עיר הקודש

holy city.

Comment: I think its referring to where the teffilin were made,but I guess nowadays all have it on them

Answer (score 2):

[Avrohom Yitzchok](/users/730/avrohom-yitzchok) [has answered what "תובב״א" stands for](/a/78546); I'll tell you what "פעיה״ק" stands for: "פה עיר הקדש" ("here [in] the holy city]"). (This is what I learned years ago, I don't remember from whom/what.)