# Why do tefillin cases have the פעיה"ק and תובב"א acronyms on them?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, acronyms

[This M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78541/5275) explains the meaning of 2 common acronyms that appear on tefillin cases (the storage boxes that the tefillin are put into.) (see pictures below)

When did this minhag begin? Why are these abbreviations placed on the tefillin boxes, in particular?[image: side 1][image: side 2][image: side 3]

Comment: Most newer tefillin boxes I've seen don't have abbreviations. Mine say מי כעמך ישראל גוי אחד בארץ and others I've seen read וקשרתם… וכתבתם.

Comment: I assume those who use acronyms do so due to limited space on the boxes

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt These acronyms tend to be on red tefillin boxes. I haven't seen these in a while, myself. My boxes are quite plain - has just pictures of what look like Yerushalayim. I'll see if I can upload a pic of these boxes, eventually.  I haven't seen the writing that you describe on anything. The *Mi ke'amcha* is a nice one and I think it's based on Talmud Brachot that states that these are the words written on G-d's tefillin.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it means, but this amazon listing says these are "old style" boxes: https://www.amazon.com/Millimeter-Plastic-Tefillin-Handend-Included/dp/B00PR97KZ2

Comment: @Menachem Thanks so much for uploading the pics! OMG they must be joking - $24 + shipping for just the cases???